# Can we pass variables as commandline arguments in execvp() in c

Tags: c, execvp

Can anyone please let me know 
Whether we can pass variables as commandline arguments to execvp() in c or not.
If so,how to pass?
Is there any other way to pass variables while calling executable?

My code snippet is

```
struct sample
{
    int links[100],nodes[100],hosts[100],linkcount,nodecount,hostcount;
};

int main() 
{
    pid_t process;
    struct sample s1;
    //assigned values to all the structure members.
     const char* command ="./abc";
    process=fork();
    if(process < 0)
    {
        perror("fork failure");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(process == 0)
    {
        execvp(command,NULL);/*Can I pass entire structure as commandline argument in execvp(command,&s1,NULL)*/
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("child is dead..parent process is resuming"); 
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that calling `execvp()` with a null pointer for the second argument invokes undefined behaviour; it is likely that your code will crash.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just create a buf that holds the argument strings and an argv which is an array of pointers to arguments in buf. Here is a code snippet:

```
char *argv[128];
char buf[8192];   // Each argument string in this buffer is null-terminated.    
int argc = 0;

// ...

// The first argument is the command, so we copy it to buf and make it pointed by argv[0].
const char* command ="./abc";
strcpy(buf, command);   
argv[argc++] = buf;     
buf += strlen(command) + 1;

// The second argument will be saved after the first one in buf and is pointed by argv[1].
char * arg = itoa(s1.id, 10);
strcpy(buf, arg);
argv[argc++] = buf;

// Required.
argv[argc] = NULL;

// ...

// Then you can call execvp!
execvp(command, argv);
```

Note that this code snippet is unsafe. Please refer to Jonathan Leffler's comment below for more details.

See http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp for more details.

Comment: The `"./abc\0"` notation has a pointless second null at the end of the string.

Comment: Since `strcpy()` null terminates the string, the `*buf = '\0';` assignment is unnecessary.  If you kept it, you might as well combine it with the `buf++` as `*buf++ = '\0';`.  In theory, you should be checking the length of the command before you copy to prevent buffer overflows.  Roughly, if you couldn't use `memmove()` to copy the string, you don't know whether it is safe to copy the string.  OK; I agree that abandoning `strcpy()` is radical, but remember the thought.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much! I have made some edits according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can (with execl()), but it must be a string (`const char*`). To convert an `int` to a string, use `itoa()`. Then you can execute `./abc 10` like so:

```
execl(command, command, itoa(s1.id, 10), NULL);
```

The second argument for `itoa` is the base.

If you must use `execvp()`, you need an array of strings, where NUM_ARGS is the number of arguments:

```
char **args=malloc(sizeof(char*)*NUM_ARGS);
args[0]=itoa(s1.id, 10);
execvp(command, args);
```

Comment: Or even better `s(n)printf`, especially if you need extra formatting.

Comment: ok..Thank you.Can I pass the structure variable s1 to execvp()  instead of passing its members as  execvp(command,s1)? If so,then how to typecast and use that structure variable in abc.c@theunamedguy

Comment: @bhargavi: that would be rather hard to do.

Comment: Note that `execl()` requires a null pointer (`char *`) to mark the end of the argument list. Also, the `itoa()` value becomes `argv[0]`.  While you can pass an argument that way, it is not the conventional way to do so; you pass the 'program name' as the first argument, then `itoa(s1.id, 10)`, then a null pointer to indicate the end of arguments.

Comment: @theunamedguy:Even it is hard.I have to do.Because in my project,the structure is having some 10 int,long type of arrays and size of these arrays will be growing dynamically.SO,can u give me an idea how to pass structure variable?

Comment: @bhargavi, can you put those values in an array?

Comment: @bhargavi: all arguments to commands are simply strings.  You'll have to convert everything you want to pass to the command into a string, and make the pointers to those strings into the `argv` array.  Remember to null terminate the array of pointers, and the zeroth element of the array is (conventionally) the program name.  You should normally be able to write `execvp(argv[0], argv);` where the name of the variable is negotiable, but the name of the program should be the first element of the array of arguments.

Comment: @bhargavi, if you can find some way to convert them all to strings, then yes. But if they're separate variables, then no.